# JS - merge 2 arrays based on properties

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to merge 2 arrays of objects where the resulting array should have only objects present in array 1 (selectedNames) but with one property from corresponding objects from array 2 (nameDetails). There's one matching (unique) property to match them:

```
const selectedNames = [
  {
    id: '11'
    name: 'joe',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    name: 'bill',
  },
];

const nameDetails = [
  {
    nameId: '11',
    salary: '23422',
    location: 'New Jersey',
  },
  {
    nameId: '33',
    salary: '23424',
    location: 'New York',
  },
  {
    nameId: '22',
    salary: '99999',
    location: 'Boston',
  },
  { nameId: '44',
    salary: '323232',
    location: 'Chicago',
  },
];
```

The matching property is selectedNames.id === nameDetails.nameId. All entries in selectedNames will definitely be present in nameDetails (but not the other way round). The resulting array should look like that:

```
[
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'joe',
    salary: '23422',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    name: 'bill',
    salary: '99999'
  }
]
```

I'm a bit confused. I know it'll probably consist of .includes() and filter() and ... for merging? I'm not sure how to handle it.

Alternatively, which will probably be much easier, filter the nameDetails array to have only objects with nameId that exists (as id) in selectedNames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your example result. For example where does `id: '11111'` come from?

Are you looking for something like this maybe?

```js
const selectedNames = [
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'joe',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    name: 'bill',
  },
];

const nameDetails = [
  {
    nameId: '11',
    salary: '23422',
    location: 'New Jersey',
  },
  {
    nameId: '33',
    salary: '23424',
    location: 'New York',
  },
  {
    nameId: '22',
    salary: '99999',
    location: 'Boston',
  },
  { nameId: '44',
    salary: '323232',
    location: 'Chicago',
  },
];

const merged = selectedNames.map(n => {
  n.salary = nameDetails.filter(d => n.id === d.nameId)[0].salary;
  return n;
});

console.log(merged)
```

Note: This will change the original `selectedNames` by adding the `salary` from the corresponding entry in `nameDetails`.

Comment: Carabus are you sure this will update/modify the `selectedNames`  or create a new one?

Comment: @rajabraza, it will create a new array instance so `merged === selectedNames` will be false, however the objects themselves are not cloned. Both arrays will point to the same objects.

Comment: @Dinh Sorry, the 1111 was a typo. It's supposed to be matching the IDs above. eg. 11, 22, 33, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this fits your needs:

```
selectedNames.map(({ id, name }) => {
    let salary = nameDetails.find((nameItem) => nameItem.nameId === id).salary;
    return { id, name, salary };
})
```

Will result in:

```
[
  {
    id: '11',
    name: 'joe',
    salary: '23422',
  },
  {
    id: '22',
    name: 'bill',
    salary: '99999',
  }
]
```